# list is not displayed after loading the data but when the display is turned off and on list is displayed

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

list view is not displayed after loading the data but when the screen display is turned off and on list is displayed.don't know whats happening.i am using xiamoi mi phone to test the app if any other activities  code requires just let me know

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class FriendList extends ListActivity {

    String email;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        email = bundle.getString("email");

        setContentView(R.layout.contacts_list);

        final List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();

        /** This block is for getting the image url to download from the server **/
        final GetDataFromDB getvalues = new GetDataFromDB();

        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(FriendList.this,
               "", "Gettting values from DB", true);
        new    Thread   (new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String response = getvalues.getImageURLAndDesciptionFromDB(email);
                System.out.println("Response : " + response);


                if (!response.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    if (!response.equalsIgnoreCase("error")) {

                        dismissDialog(dialog);
                        // Got the response, now split it to get the image Urls and description
                        String all[] = response.split("\\|::endline::\\|");
                        for(int k = 0; k < all.length; k++){
                            String urls_and_desc[] = all[k].split("\\|::break::\\|"); //  urls_and_desc[0] contains image url and [1] -> description
                            System.out.println("image url : " + urls_and_desc[2]);

                            list.add(get(urls_and_desc[1], "https://xxxx.xx/" + urls_and_desc[2]));


                        }
                    }

                } else {
                   dismissDialog(dialog);
                }
            }
        }).start();
        /*************************** GOT data from Server ********************************************/

        ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter = new MyCustomArrayAdapter(this, list);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        setListAdapter(adapter);


    }

    public void dismissDialog(final ProgressDialog dialog){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    private Model get(String s, String url) {
        return new Model(s, url);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `((ArrayAdapter<Model>)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged()` after fetching data from server:

```
new    Thread   (new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            String response = getvalues.getImageURLAndDesciptionFromDB(email);
            System.out.println("Response : " + response);


            if (!response.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                if (!response.equalsIgnoreCase("error")) {

                    dismissDialog(dialog);
                    // Got the response, now split it to get the image Urls and description
                    String all[] = response.split("\\|::endline::\\|");
                    for(int k = 0; k < all.length; k++){
                        String urls_and_desc[] = all[k].split("\\|::break::\\|"); //  urls_and_desc[0] contains image url and [1] -> description
                        System.out.println("image url : " + urls_and_desc[2]);

                        list.add(get(urls_and_desc[1], "https://xxxx.xx/" + urls_and_desc[2]));
                    }
                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ((ArrayAdapter<Model>)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();//Notify ListView to update itself.
                        }
                   });
                }

            } else {
               dismissDialog(dialog);
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: i tried this but i got error like "cannot resolve method notifyDataSetChanged"

Comment: I update my answer. You should cast the adapter returned by `getListAdapter()` to an `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: it shows error like "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views".

Comment: Why not use an AsyncTask? run asynchronous code in doInBackground(), update on UI thread using onPostExecute().